# Having trouble building ardour, can anyone help me with dependencies? I have tried reinstalling everything to no avail

Tags: dependencies, compiling, gcc, ardour

I'm having trouble building Ardour. Can anyone help me with dependencies? I have tried reinstalling everything to no avail.

```
luis@Luis-Macbook:~/Downloads/music/DAW/ardour/ardour$ ./waf configure
Setting top to                           : /home/luis/Downloads/music/DAW/ardour/ardour 
Setting out to                           : /home/luis/Downloads/music/DAW/ardour/ardour/build 
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++ 

Global Configuration 
 * Install prefix                                    : /usr/local 
 * Debuggable build                                  : True 
 * Build documentation                               : False 

Ardour Configuration 
 * Will build against private GTK dependency stack   : no 
 * Will rely on libintl built into libc              : yes 
 * Will build against private Ardour dependency stack : no 
Checking for function 'dlopen' in dlfcn.h            : yes 
Checking for boost library >= 1.56                   : ok 
Checking for program 'pkg-config'                    : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
Checking for 'alsa'                                  : yes 
Checking for 'libpulse'                              : yes 
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.28                      : yes 
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.68                      : not found 
Checking for 'gthread-2.0' >= 2.2                    : yes 
Checking for 'glibmm-2.4' >= 2.32.0                  : yes 
Checking for 'sndfile' >= 1.0.18                     : yes 
Checking for 'giomm-2.4' >= 2.2                      : yes 
Checking for 'libcurl' >= 7.0.0                      : yes 
Checking for 'libarchive' >= 3.0.0                   : yes 
Checking for 'liblo' >= 0.26                         : not found 
The configuration failed
(complete log in /home/luis/Downloads/music/DAW/ardour/ardour/build/config.log)

log 
Checking for 'liblo' >= 0.26 ['/usr/bin/pkg-config', 'liblo >= 0.26', '--cflags', '--libs', 'liblo'] 
err: Package liblo was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing liblo.pc' 
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'liblo' found Package liblo was not found in the pkg-config search path. 
Perhaps you should add the directory containing liblo.pc' 
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'liblo' found 

Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.68
['/usr/bin/pkg-config', 'glib-2.0 >= 2.68', '--cflags', '--libs', 'glib-2.0']
err: Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.68' but version of GLib is 2.56.4
not found
```

Ubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: Look at the complete log in `/home/luis/Downloads/DAW/ardour/ardour/build/config.log` like the message says.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it says clearly

```
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.28    : yes 
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.68    : not found 
...
...
Checking for 'glib-2.0' >= 2.68
['/usr/bin/pkg-config', 'glib-2.0 >= 2.68', '--cflags', '--libs', 'glib-2.0']
err: Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.68' but version of GLib is 2.56.4
```

Which is consistent with my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: It has Glib 2.56.4. The package name is `libglib2.0-2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.8`, the -dev package which you need for building software is `libglib2.0-dev-2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.8`.

But it wants the newer Glib 2.68. Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have that. Since it insists on that newer Glib, your only option is to upgrade your Ubuntu; not sure if using a PPA for libglib2.0 would help, or if it would break other software that you have installed.

But you can simply install "ardour" from standard 18.04 repositories:

```
apt search ardour

ardour/bionic 1:5.12.0-3 amd64
  the digital audio workstation

ardour-data/bionic,bionic 1:5.12.0-3 all
  digital audio workstation (data)

ardour-video-timeline/bionic,bionic 1:5.12.0-3 all
  digital audio workstation - video timeline
```

https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/ardour/

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ardour
```

Comment: thanks this was my fix